# Proper installation of Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 14.06 to include IDLE

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-idle

I am trying to install Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 14.06.  I have tried the get-apt command and I have tried to install from a tarball.  Either way this is the error I receive.

```
:~/Downloads$ pip install Python-43.4.6.tar.gz 
Requirement 'Python-43.4.6.tar.gz' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist 
Processing ./Python-43.4.6.tar.gz 
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main     status = self.run(options, args)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run     wb.build(autobuilding=True)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build     self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files     ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file     session=self.session, hashes=hashes)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 798, in unpack_url     unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 705, in unpack_file_url     unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 620, in unpack_file     tarfile.is_tarfile(filename) or   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2622, in is_tarfile     t = open(name)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1673, in open     return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1738, in gzopen     fileobj = gzip.GzipFile(name, mode, compresslevel, fileobj)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 94, in __init__     fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb') 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/michael/Downloads/Python-43.4.6.tar.gz' 

You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. 

:~/Downloads$ pip install --upgrade pip 
Collecting pip   
Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)     100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 662kB/s  Installing collected packages: pip 
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1 
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. 

~/Downloads$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

~/Downloads$ python -V
Python 2.7.12

~/Downloads$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Did I download the wrong tarball or is there a way to insure that I am not install with for Python 2.7?  Also, is the pip version error related?

TIA

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 14.06.

Comment: `Python-43.4.6.tar.gz` isn't a valid tarball. And using pip to install Python makes no sense.

Comment: One bash script. No tarball. https://conda.io/docs/install/quick.html#linux-miniconda-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try using the upgrade command in pip and see if that fixes the version problem

```
 pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

otherwise I would recommend uninstalling and performing a fresh install.

Use the following commands to setup python

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get -y upgrade
 sudo apt-get install python3.6 python3-pip idle3
 pip3 install numpy
 pip3 install spyder
```

pip3 is the command for using python installer for python3.

to use idle3, just type in into the command window

```
 idle3
```

I suggest to install spyder using pip3 as spyder is a more advanced idle which can track variables and code writing. makes it a bit easier in locating errors and such.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Many linux distribution provide tkinter, IDLE (which uses tkinter), and turtle (which also uses tkinter) as separate distribution.  Searching SO for `[tkinter] install tkinter on ubuntu` displays previous questions with answers.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

may be what you need but details may have change since previous answers.